# Catch script output of SQL statement executed from python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, logging, output

catch script output of SQL statement executed from python.tried all possible ways i knew.

i have a py script which takes sql script file and execute the statements in a series.

i am not able to catch the output of these executions.
for ex: create table...table created
        update table.....anonymous block completed

```
  'try:
        # session = subprocess.Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', connectString '@'+destPath+ '\\' +fileName])
        session = subprocess.Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', connectString], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        query = command.encode('utf-8')
        session.stdin.write(query)
        # stdout, stderr = session.communicate(destPath+ '\\' +fileName)[0]
        stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
        f =  open(outPath+'\\' +'%s' % fileName, 'a')
        f.write(stdout.decode("unicode"))
        f.write(stdout)
        # f.write(stderr)
        f.close()'
```

and the file is empty...or if i try to print stdout, it gives "b'" or "none"

Comment: Why are you running SQL commands by calling out to sqlplus? You should use the appropriate library to call your db directly.

Comment: tried this either    cx_Oracle, MySQLdb....but not able to achieve the intended result.